# How do I take the string from the login and display it on a profile page?

Tags: java, android, string, authentication

Below is my working login code. I now want the 'name' the person logged in with to be displayed on a profile page. Searched all over but could not find it.

For example:
Person logged in with name 'example@mail.com' ('username' in code below). I want 'example@mail.com' to be displayed on a `TextView` on a different page.

Thanks for the help!

```
private EditText editTextUserName;
private EditText editTextPassword;

public static final String USER_NAME = "USERNAME";

String username;
String password;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editTextUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUserName);
    editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);

}

public void invokeLogin(View view){
    username = editTextUserName.getText().toString();
    password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();

    login(username,password);
}

private void login(final String username, String password) {

    class LoginAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        private Dialog loadingDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loadingDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Please wait", "Loading...");
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String uname = params[0];
            String pass = params[1];

            InputStream is = null;
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", uname));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pass));
            String result = null;

            try{
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
                        "http://calisapp.esy.es/login.php");
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                is = entity.getContent();

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                result = sb.toString();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            String s = result.trim();
            loadingDialog.dismiss();
            if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("success")){
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserProfile.class);
                intent.putExtra(USER_NAME, username);
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                editTextUserName.requestFocus();
                editTextUserName.setError("Wrong E-mail address or password");
            }
        }
    }

    LoginAsync la = new LoginAsync();
    la.execute(username, password);

}
```

Comment: Use `SharedPreferences`.

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways, you can do this
 1. Using [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)
 2. Storing the value on [Local Database](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db)
 3. Passing the value via [Intent](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html).

Comment: Oh. What I posted below is not working. Did not even test it, thought it was flawless seeing it worked on my main page test to say 'welcome 'user''. Any idea why? The code is below on my answer.

Comment: check my answer below

Comment: I think I have to use startactivity() to be able to get the string on a diff. activity? I do not want to send them to the settings page, just want the string though. Is that possible?

Comment: why do you want to send the string, if you don't want to send the users to settings screen.

Comment: So when they do go to the settings page they can see their e-mail address. Your edit crashes my application though!

Comment: but i just showed you, how to pass variables from one activity to another.

Comment: See now I have added the startactivity() and it works, but I really want the persons email address to be displayed everytime he visits the settings page.

Comment: store the email in sharedPreferences
and get it on settings page

Answer (score 0):

If their login is successful, use SharedPreferences to store it. Something like this:

```
SharedPreferences myPrefs = getSharedPreferences(PREF_KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

myPrefs.edit().putString(EMAIL_KEY, someEmail@example.com).apply();
myPrefs.edit().putString(PASSWORD_KEY, somePassword).apply();
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: DOES NOT WORK FOR SOME REASON.

Thanks guys. I did not know you could use multiple intents so I did that. If anyone happens to need to know how I did it. Probably better to use shared preferences but I just need it on one more page for now, and I'm not a fan of making things harder than they could be.

I added a second intent to the login class on successfull login, that will carry the username string over to my settings/profile.

```
Intent intent2 = new Intent (MainActivity.this, Settings.class);
intent2.putExtra(USER_NAME, username);
```

On the settings page I called it by a intent.getStringExtra. I used a textview to show the string.

```
  Intent intent2 = getIntent();
    String username = intent2.getStringExtra(MainActivity.USER_NAME);

    TextView showEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.SettingsShowEmail);
    showEmail.setText(username);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Intent intent2 = new Intent (MainActivity.this, Settings.class);
intent2.putExtra("username", username);
startActivity(intent2);
```

on the settings activity

```
String username = getIntent().getExtras().getString("username");
TextView showEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.SettingsShowEmail);
showEmail.setText(username);
```

Comment: Trying it now. Seems weird to me that it won't work in the way I did it just cause I don't use a startactivity().

Comment: what comment do you want me to add